# Не получается разобраться с Ajax и getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, валидация

есть сервер http://codeit.pro/frontTestTask/user/registration.
Который по стандарту возвращает объект:

```
{"message":"Field 'name' is required","field":"name","status":"Form Error"}
```

Если я прохожу все этапы валидации в своей форме(на своей странице), то на сервере появляется объект:

```
{"message":"User created","status":"OK"}
```

Когда использую следующий код, то получается что даже если я прошел все этапы валидации в консоль(моей страницы) возвращает стандартный объект, а мне нужно получить новый объект. Код:

```
$("#button").click(function (event) {
    // event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://codeit.pro/frontTestTask/user/registration',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Цель: после отправки формы получить в консоль(своей страницы), корректный, новый объект. Спасибо

**Данные которые нужно отправлять из этой формы**

```html
<form id="signUpForm" target="iframe1" method="post"
      action="http://codeit.pro/frontTestTask/user/registration">
    <!--name-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"
               id="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <!--secondname-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input value="abcd" type="text" name="secondname"
               class="form-control" id="secondname" minlength="3"
               maxlength="60" placeholder="Secondname">
    </div>
    <!--e-mail-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input value="abcd@abcd.com" type="email" name="email"
               class="form-control" id="email"
               placeholder="name@example.com">
    </div>
    <!--gender-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!--password-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input value="abcd" type="password" name="pass"
               class="form-control" id="password"
               placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <!--checkbox-->
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
        Conditions of Agreement
        </label>
    </div>
    <!--sendBtn-->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"
            id="button">Send</button>
```

Comment: А где в вашем запросе данные, которые вы отправляете на сервер? Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Может в этом и дело. Как должно, по идее как, быть?

Comment: @user8365703 какие данные нужны, чтобы получить ответ `{"message":"User created","status":"OK"}`?

Comment: @Cheg данные формы. input name, secondname, email password должны быть заполнены

Comment: @Cheg добавил форму которая есть у меня

Comment: @user8365703 где можно посмотреть документацию о том, как именно должен выглядеть запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужный запрос может выглядеть так:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://codeit.pro/frontTestTask/user/registration',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        secondname: $('#secondname').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        gender: $('#gender').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(textStatus);
});
```

Comment: Добавил форму которая у меня есть.

Comment: Все отлично!
только вместо password: $('#password').val()
нужно pass: $('#password').val()
потому что сервер принимает pass

Comment: Только сделайте отступы по человечески

Comment: Еще вопрос: Как отсюда же, при успешном прохождении делать редирект на другую страницу?

Comment: @tutankhamun без проблем! Спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 0):

Думаю этот вариант вам получше подойдет, зачем париться и писать каждый параметр вручную, лучше сериализовать форму  в переменную, а потом по необходимости добавить что необходимо. Редирект тоже вставил.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#signUpForm button[type=submit]').click(function() {
    var data_hash = $('#signUpForm [name]').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://codeit.pro/frontTestTask/user/registration',
      dataType: "json",
      data: data_hash,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        window.location.href = '/to_redirect/';
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="signUpForm" target="iframe1" method="post" action="http://codeit.pro/frontTestTask/user/registration">
  <!--name-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <!--secondname-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input value="abcd" type="text" name="secondname" class="form-control" id="secondname" minlength="3" maxlength="60" placeholder="Secondname">
  </div>
  <!--e-mail-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input value="abcd@abcd.com" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
  <!--gender-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender">
      <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!--password-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input value="abcd" type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <!--checkbox-->
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Conditions of Agreement
  </div>
  <!--sendBtn-->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: А еще у вас в форме ошибка, есть закрывающий ТЭГ </label> но нет открывающего